# Earliest viewer for viewing .json files?

Tags: debian, text-processing, editors, text, json

While almost all text-editors can view .json files, I am sure there are some or one which show .json files in all its glory. Could somebody share name or names of native .json viewers rather than text-editors which can also show .json files. I am looking to know about the earliest tools which are/were used to view .json files. Looking to see raw .json output rather than pretty output.

Comment: JSON *is* plain text. This question makes no sense. If you don't want syntax highlighting, just turn it off in your editor.

Comment: any format text or otherwise need to have support built-in from an app. My aim was two-fold, to understand the code which makes up .json file so I could replicate the same and to have some sort of historical perspective as to where it came from.

Comment: *JSON is plain ASCII text*. Anything that that reads plain text can read it. There is no need for a special app, just as there is no need for a special app for reading HTML or just about any other markup or programming languages. If you want to have a historical perspective, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#History - if you want an overview of the syntax, read the next section on the same page.

Comment: Yes, this question is strange, but I for once got here because I was looking for a GUI viewer of JSON, which can show it in a tree (colapse etc.), and maybe also handle jsonpath or some other search mechanism. At least some standalone viewer which can do as much as the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Nevermind, opening the JSON with Firefox does the trick for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "earliest" and "most basic" tool I can think of that may be used to display the contents of a JSON file is `cat`:

```
$ cat file.json
```

This will not do pretty-printing and it will show the "raw JSON", i.e. the file as it is.

The `cat` utility was [available in at least the 2nd release of Unix from Bell Labs](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V2-Snapshot-Development/cmd/cat.s) in around 1972.

The JSON format was first introduced [in the early 2000s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Answer (score 11):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a json processor (like sed for json) which can also be used to pretty-print json documents.

```
 cat yourfile.json | jq
```

Comment: I have updated my question so its better understood what I'm looking for.

Comment: Also `jq . file.json`.

Comment: very nice utilite))